# How to set different color for different listview item in kendoUI

Tags: listview, model-view-controller, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am showing Items in Listview as below: 
[image]

How to display different color of the listview item according to status? e.g. 
[image]

Here is the sample kendo ui code I have implimented.

```html
<script type="text/x-kendo-tmpl" id="template">
  <div class="product">
    <h3>#:CustomerVersion#</h3>
    <h5>#:Rank#</h5>
    <h3>#:AccountType#</h3>
  </div>
</script>


<div class="demo-section">
  @Code Dim listName = "List" Dim listViewRankBar = Html.Kendo().ListView(Of RankBarModel)() With listViewRankBar .Name(listName) .TagName("div") .ClientTemplateId("template") .DataSource(Sub(datasource) datasource.Read(Sub(read) read.Action("Products_Read",
  "RankBar")) datasource.PageSize(15) End Sub) .Selectable(Sub(selectable) selectable.Enabled(True) selectable.Mode(ListViewSelectionMode.Single) End Sub) .Events(Sub(events) events.Change("onChange").DataBound("onDataBound") End Sub) '.Pageable() End
  With End Code @listViewRankBar
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your status field is `Status` it would be similar to this:

```
<script type="text/x-kendo-tmpl" id="template">
  <div class="product #if (Status == 'Active') {# active #} else {# inactive #}#">
    <h3>#:CustomerVersion#</h3>
    <h5>#:Rank#</h5>
    <h3>#:AccountType#</h3>
  </div>
</script>
```

A running sample can be found here: http://dojo.telerik.com/@mmillican/iDOSu